# Add Gift Messages in the Billing Information section in Magento checkout

Tags: php, magento

I want to display the `Gift message option` in **Billing Information** section in `Magento checkout`.

Currently this option is showing in **shipping method** section in `magento checkout.`

How can I do this? I am using `magento 1.9.0.1.`

Please help..

Comment: Update the same code in billing template file also

Comment: @ Pavan Kumar, Billing information lies in frontend\mytemplate\mytemplate\template\persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml page, and gift option is in frontend\base\default\template\giftmessage/inline.phtml page. However I copy all code from inline.phtml and paste in billing.phtml, but the page gives error -cannot display because of security reason.

Comment: can u paste ur code that how u r displaying it in shipping method section

Answer (score 1):

1. Goto your current theme package and open a file which is currently taken **checkout->onepage->shipping_method->additional.phtml**  remove the below lines.

   ```
   <div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional') ?>
   </div>
   ```
2. Then goto **checkout->onepage->billing.phtml** add the below lines wherever you want to show gift message in billing section.

   ```
    <div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
      <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/onepage_shipping_method_additional')->setTemplate('checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
   ```